# GittyUp - Git-Client: Unable to see the changed files list on the right of the `Diff` window

Tags: git, client

I'm using `GittyUp` as my git client
I'm on `M1 Pro` with `Ventura 13.6.1`

`GittyUp` version - `1.3.0 - 6bf49f0`

The changed files list is hidden for me. I hid it to make more space to check the diff, but then now, i'm unable to see the changed files list window back.

This is what i see -
[image: This is what i see..]

This is what i want to see
[image: This is what i want to see]

I have tried `deleting` and `re-installing` the app, but for some reason, the `settings` are stored somewhere and it shows the same `image 1` upon starting up fresh. Thus, `unable` to `reset the settings` either.